# How to set focus to a div element in a react component using useEffect and useRef hooks? And how to test it?

Tags: react-testing-library

All most all the articles and examples about setting focus are explained using input element. It works well with input element but how to **set focus to a div element** using React useRef and useEffect hooks?

How to test it using `toHaveFocus` of *react-testing-library*?

Answer (score 16):

After searching for a while and wasting quite a bit of time, I was able to do it. Sharing it here for friends!!

**Component file SetFocusToDivComponent.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function SetFocusToDivComponent() {

  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current.focus();
  });

  return (
    <div
      data-test={'container'}
      ref={errorDisplayWrapperRef}
      tabIndex={-1}
    >
      Hello There!!
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test file SetFocusToDivComponent.tests.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import SetFocusToDivComponent from './SetFocusToDivComponent';

let container;

beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  document.body.removeChild(container);
  container = null;
});

test('setting focus', () => {
  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<SetFocusToDivComponent />, container);
  });
  expect(container.querySelector('div[data-test="container"]')).toHaveFocus();
});
```

If you are using a styled div instead of plain html div, then use `innerRef` instead of `ref`

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
`;

<StyledDiv
  data-test={'container'}
  innerRef={errorDisplayWrapperRef}
  tabIndex={-1}
>
  Hello There!!
</StyledDiv>
```

**PS:** Don't forget tabIndex