# ReactJS How to use Refs on components rendered dinamically by another render function to focus elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component that Renders a list of elements and I need to focus them when an event occurs.

Here is an example code

```
class page extends React.Component {
   state = {
      items: [array of objects]
   }

   renderList = () => {
      return this.state.items.map(i => <button>{i.somekey}</button>)
   }

   focusElement = (someitem) => {
      //Focus some item rendered by renderList()
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            {this.renderList()}
            <button onClick={() => focusElement(thatElement)}>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

I know that I need to use refs but I tried several ways to do that and I couldn't set those refs properly.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which element, specifically, do you need to focus?

Comment: <button> rendered by renderList() in this case

Comment: It looks like `renderList` renders more than one button, though. Which one should get focus?

Comment: Seems this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264417/how-to-set-focus-to-a-div-element-in-a-react-component-using-useeffect-and-usere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the `createRef`method of each button that you would like to focus, also you have to pass this ref to the `focusElement` method that you have created:

```
const myList = [
  { id: 0, label: "label0" },
  { id: 1, label: "label1" },
  { id: 2, label: "label2" },
  { id: 3, label: "label3" },
  { id: 4, label: "label4" },
  { id: 5, label: "label5" }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: myList,
    //This is the list of refs that will help you pick any item that ou want to focus
    myButtonsRef: myList.map(i => React.createRef(i.label))
  };

  // Here you create a ref for each button
  renderList = () => {
    return this.state.items.map(i => (
      <button key={i.id} ref={this.state.myButtonsRef[i.id]}>
        {i.label}
      </button>
    ));
  };

  //Here you pass the ref as an argument and just focus it
  focusElement = item => {
    item.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderList()}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            //Here you are able to focus any item that you want based on the ref in the state
            this.focusElement(this.state.myButtonsRef[0]);
          }}
        >
          Focus the item 0
        </button>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mayer-g2xdy) if you want to play with the code

Comment: Thanks for your response.Exactly what I needed! But how should I create this refs if myList data comes from an async list?

Comment: When you get the `response` and set the `items` in the `state`, is the best time to create the `refs` too, probably you are doing it in `componentDidMount` if not, you should do it there.

Comment: I did it on ComponentDidMount but I don't know why all Refs in state's list are Object { current: null } and I can't access them

Comment: Just be sure that you are rendering the buttons, after the refs are created

Comment: I saw my fault. I was creating the refs on a list of div components, when referenced in button, it worked. Can you explain why that occurs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but check the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), it is the most reliable source of knowledge

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot!!